# How to show a function in a sequence diagram that is implemented by multiple interfaces?

Tags: function, interface, uml, sequence-diagram

I want to draw a sequence diagram.
A class calls a function f for an instance of class B.
Class B is implemented by two interfaces, X, and Y.

Both X and Y implement f. How should I denote that the f function comes from either interface X or Y?

Comment: Classes **implemented by** interfaces?

Comment: If you mean that `B` **implements** two interfaces `X` and `Y`, is `X.f` the same as `Y.f`, or are they different methods? If they are different, why does the function come from *either* interface? (I assume that in the implementation of A would know if it want to invoke `X.f` or `Y.f`)

Comment: @Javier Yes, the class is implemented by interfaces. And yes, I mean indeed X.f or Y.f where we want to show in the UML diagram which f is called (either X.f or Y.f). Probably a just X.f on the line in the sequence diagram from the calling class to class B will do but I wondered if the . on the line is 'proper' UML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `X::f` or `Y::f` (i.e. two colons instead of dot)

The UML specification says that

> A CallEvent is denoted by the name of the triggering Operation (...)
>
> ```
> <call-event> ::= <name> [‘(‘ [<assignment-specification>] ‘)’]
> ```

Interface is a specialization of Namespace (via Classifier), then the following applies:

> If a member of a Namespace with the name N is a NamedElement with the name x, then the member can be referred to by a qualified name of the form N::x.

Comment: Thanks ... too bad Borland Together does not support this (it thinks that the part after : is a return value and removes it from the arrow to the time line.